# Why am I not receiving information from the api in siwft ui?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am working on a project in Xcode using Swift and I'm having trouble fetching data from an API.

In my code, I have defined a Politician struct that conforms to the Codable and Identifiable protocols, and I have also created an API class that uses URLSession to fetch data from the API.

I have a List in my ContentView that should display the names of the politicians, and I am using a sheet to display more details about a selected politician in a new view. However, when I run the app, I get an error message saying "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format" and no data is displayed in the list.

**Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this error and how to fix it so that the data is displayed correctly in the list?**

I'm a noob and I even watched a whole udemy tutorial about json, but I'm still so frustrated because I'm trying to make it work for schoolc

I created a structure. I used only a few data information, because I just want to learn it. I'm not sure if I need to create a structure for all data even without using it to make it work. I used json to fetch the api via url. I created a content view list and I hope it displays every id separately and after a click you'll see a single page with different api informations
3

Sources for api:
https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians
https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/response

code

```
    import SwiftUI

struct Politician: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let birthYear: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case birthYear = "birth_year"
    }
}

class PoliticianService {
    func fetchPoliticians(completion: @escaping ([Politician]?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians") else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let politicians = try JSONDecoder().decode([Politician].self, from: data)
                completion(politicians)
            } catch {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func fetchPolitician(id: Int, completion: @escaping (Politician?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians\(id)") else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let politician = try JSONDecoder().decode(Politician.self, from: data)
                completion(politician)
            } catch {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

class PoliticianListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var politicians = [Politician]()

    func fetchPoliticians() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let politicians = try decoder.decode([Politician].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.politicians = politicians
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = PoliticianListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.politicians, id: \.id) { politician in
                NavigationLink(destination: PoliticianDetailView(politician: politician)) {
                    Text("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Politicians")
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchPoliticians()
        }
    }
}

struct PoliticianDetailView: View {
    let politician: Politician
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
            Text("Birth year: \(politician.birthYear)")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Politician Details")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to check out [ask]. Without including your code (ideally, a [mre]), it's impossible to debug your issue.

Comment: Use `print(error)` not `print(error.localizedDescription)`

Comment: Oh no I can't do this on my phone, I get error that I need to change the code... I'll repost later

Comment: Please edit this question. Do not post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little project cleanup goes a long way towards figuring out what's going on! Let's take a look:

First, let's rewrite your `fetchPoliticians()` function so that it uses Swift Concurrency, instead of callback-handlers. For someone who's just getting started, these are a lot easier to read and a lot safer to use:

```swift
func fetchPoliticians() async throws -> [Politician] {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians") else { return [] }
        
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode([Politician].self, from: data)
}
```

This code does the exact same thing as your existing function with the completion handler. It's just written using Swift Concurrency. A lot easier to reason about now, right?

Because this function `throws` an error and doesn't do any custom error handling now (it just rethrows any errors provided from either `URLSession` or `JSONDecoder`), we actually start seeing very helpful errors in the debug console:

```bash
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

The juicy part of the error is this message:

> Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.

This is an error from the `JSONDecoder` object. Your network request succeeded and was able to get data back. But, the response couldn't be converted to your expected format (an array of `Politician` objects). Why? Because the returned data is a dictionary, not an array.

This should lead us to to another conclusion: maybe the API isn't returning what we are expecting? Our code compiles, we get a response, and are *almost* able to parse it. So let's take a look at what the endpoint is returning for this call:

```json
"meta": {
  ...
},
"data": [
  {
    "id": 179808,
    "entity_type": "politician",
    "label": "Harald Braun",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Sure enough! It looks like the API is giving us a dictionary with a bit more information than we were prepared to accept. Let's create a new type called `Politicians` and map to that instead:

```swift
struct Politicians: Codable {
    let data: [Politician]
}

actor PoliticianService {
    
    func fetchPoliticians() async throws -> [Politician] {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians") else { return [] }
        
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let politicians = try decoder.decode(Politicians.self, from: data)
        return politicians.data
    }

    ...

}
```

Now, you should be able to update your ViewModel to work with the `async` function you wrote:

```swift
// Notice the @MainActor attribute here? This indicates that code from 
// this object should always get called on the main thread. What does 
// that mean? You won't need to worry about blocking your UI while you're
// waiting for your politicians variable to update from network!
//
@MainActor class PoliticianListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var politicians = [Politician]()
    
    private var service = PoliticianService()
    
    init() {
        
    }
    
    // Your function can just make the call to your PoliticiansService!
    // No need to duplicate the function in your view model too. That's
    // the beauty of functions!
    //
    func fetchPoliticians() {
        // Since this class is now a "Main Actor" we need to use a "Task"
        // to call our async function.
        Task {
            do {
                // Call our async function using try await...
                let leaders = try await service.fetchPoliticians()
                politicians = leaders
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Once you run this, you'll notice two more issues:

1. The key for birth year is `year_of_birth`, not `birth_year`.
2. Some entries don't include a `year_of_birth`, so you'll need to make that value **optional** in your `Politician` struct -- or provide a default value for it.

A tip moving forward when working with APIs: use a service like [Postman](https://postman.com) or [Paw](https://paw.cloud) to test out an API and understand what its returning. It can be painful to work in the dark without knowing what kind of data you'll be getting back.

---

The final working result:

[image: Screenshot of iPhone Simulator running an app with a list of politicians]

Comment: Thank you for the effort , it took me some time to fully understand it and make it work. Currently I experience again errors and try to use postman, but how do you even use it correctly :P

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing? As for Postman, they have [a wonderful series of articles](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/first-steps/sending-the-first-request/) explaining how to use the tool (as well as an introduction to basic API concepts. You should check them out!